# Get time which can not be changed by the user

Tags: java, android, datetime

Is it possible in Android to get a time / date, which can not be manipulated by the user?

I mean in Android you can edit the system time and if you remove the battery the time is reseted too. Of course you can get the current time from a server on the internet but (improbable but is would work) then the user is able to intercept the request and send an own time back.

I do not know much about GPS. Is there a time stamp and is it possible that the user can replace it? I really want a time which can definitely not be changed by the user. Is that possible?

Comment: In a word, "no".  Whatever you do, someone can undo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can never trust the client. If this is really as absolutely crucial as you're saying, see if it's possible to offload whatever it is you're doing to a server that's under your control.